# perl script cannot find modules because of permission problems

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that runs when I run it as superuser and it does not run when I am a normal user. I installed Perl from sources and typed make install as superuser. I guess this created a perl database for the modules and now normal users cannot read it. Do you know where this database is or anything else I could do about the situation?

Comment: It is actually the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254352/how-can-i-fix-broken-perl-permissions

Answer (score 0):

The script used /usr/bin/perl, which was the old Mac-Perl. The problem was caused by an unaccessable directory:

/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level

This was not readable for normal users. I changed this and now it works again.

sudo /usr/bin/perl -V

provided me with the pathes to look for problems. The update path above does not contain the .pm files, Perl complains about, but it has to be readable.